# Implicit conversion for explicit operator

Tags: c++, std

I've encountered a strange behavior (in my eyes) of vector::emplace_back() in gcc (version 6.3.1). It implicitly casts a type to another one even though the conversion operator declared as explicit.

```
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(double value) :
        value{value}
    {}

    explicit operator double() const
    {
        return value;
    }

private:
    double value;
};

int main()
{
    A a{0.0};
    std::vector<double> values;
    values.emplace_back(a); // <- no error here!    

    return 0;
}
```

Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: `emplace_back` builds explicitly from the given parameter.

Comment: You would get a error with `push_back` though.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically as Jarod42 wrote in the comments, but here are some details.

The [`emplace_back` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) emplaces an element which

> is constructed through std::allocator_traits::construct

If you look at [`construct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct), you can see it uses [placement `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). It is essentially something like

```
new((void *)p) T(val)
```

which is an explicit ctor call.

Answer (score 0):

From ISO [class.conv.fct]:

> A conversion function may be explicit (7.1.2), in which case it is
>   only considered as a user-defined conversion for direct-initialization
>   (8.5). Otherwise, user-defined conversions are not restricted to use
>   in assignments and initializations.

```
double b { A { .0 } }; // fine
double d = A { .0 }; // wrong
```